# Why does my release .exe fail on launch for a UWP application?

Tags: uwp

This is probably the dumbest question here. I'm just getting into UWP and when I build the release configuration it fails to launch the exe I would expect me to be able to launch. Here are the steps taken. I start a new project "MyUWPProject" made with the "Blank App(Universal Windows) Visual C#" template. It loads in Visual Studio 2017 and I switch the configuration over to "Release | x86" then build. I get the path "\MyUWPProject\MyUWPProject\bin\x86\Release\MyUWPProject.exe" and try to launch it only to see "MyUWPProject has stopped working" error. However, the program launches just fine when I have it in "Release | x86" configuration and hit "F5."

What steps am I missing to be able to have my .exe for launching a program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP apps are not ran via `.exe` files.  They are installed.  Once ran with F5 you can find the app in your start menu and run it again from there.

Launching a UWP .EXE is not possible.

Comment: Oh no. That's less than desirable for me. How do I distribute it to other computers of mine then?

Comment: Look into it a bit. It's a bit complicated to put in a comment but there's lots of info about it. If I was at the PC I'd post some info but I can't ATM